# Create vector of multiple structs for Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, tui

I am pretty new to Rust. So I might be doing something dumb.

For context, I am using tui-rs to make a small terminal application. This is the relevant cleaned code.

```
use tui::widgets::{Block, List, Widget};

pub struct UI {
    widgets: Vec<Box<dyn Widget>>,
}



let block = Block::default().title("Block").borders(Borders::ALL);
let list = List::new(items)
    .block(Block::default().title("List").borders(Borders::ALL))
    .style(Style::default().fg(Color::White))
    .highlight_style(Style::default().add_modifier(Modifier::ITALIC))
    .highlight_symbol(">>");

let widgets = vec![Box::new(block),Box::new(list)];

for i in 0..self.widgets.len() {
    f.render_widget(self.widgets[i], self.chunks[i]);
}
...
```

Now you get the idea about what I am trying to achieve. But i keep getting this error on
`f.render_widget(self.widgets[i], self.chunks[i])`;

```
the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<dyn tui::widgets::Widget>: tui::widgets::Widget` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `tui::widgets::Widget`:
  tui::widgets::BarChart<'a>
  tui::widgets::Block<'a>
  tui::widgets::Chart<'a>
  tui::widgets::Clear
  tui::widgets::Gauge<'a>
  tui::widgets::LineGauge<'a>
  tui::widgets::List<'a>
  tui::widgets::Paragraph<'a>
and 4 othersrustcE0277
terminal.rs(99, 12): required by a bound in `tui::Frame::<'a, B>::render_widget`
```

I have even tried the enum approach

```
struct Widgets{
    List,
    Box
}

pub struct UI {
    widgets: Vec<Widgets>,
}
let widgets = vec![block,list];
```

Now the error is on `let widgets = vec![block,list];`

```
mismatched types
expected enum `ui::Widgets`, found struct `tui::widgets::List`
```

Comment: Have you tried getting reference of the widget inside the box? `f.render_widget(&self.widgets[i], &self.chunks[i])`. I wouldn't expect tui to require the widget by value, and it certainly doesn't expect a box.

Comment: @MaximGritsenko: I think `tui` does [take widgets by value](https://docs.rs/tui/latest/tui/terminal/struct.Frame.html#method.render_widget). So no `dyn` objects allowed.

Comment: Well, then they cannot be in the `Vec` obviously. So using `*boxed_widget` should fix the issue. I believe `dyn Widget` implements `Widget` trait.

Comment: @MaximGritsenko: I don't think that will work, because `Widget::render` takes `self` by value, so it must be of a sized type, and that `dyn Widget` is unsized.

Comment: Maybe you are fighting the system? The docs say: _[Widgets] are not meant to be stored but used as commands to draw common figures in the UI_.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not at the `vec!` step but rather at the `render_widget` step (for box way).

What is happening is that the trait `Widget` is not implemented for `Box<dyn Widget>`. It looks like the issue is at tui-rs end where they forgot to add a blanket impl for references.

You can try giving a reference like @maxim-gritsenko said: `f.render_widget(&self.widgets[i], ...)`.
I am not sure that would work, though. If it does, its probably the best solution.

The enum solution can work, but you didn't actually make the enums correctly.

What you need is something like:

```rust
enum MyWidgets {
  List(tui::widgets::List),
  Block(tui::widgets::Block),
}

let widgets = vec![MyWidgets::List(list), MyWidgets::Block(block)];

for widget in widgets {
  match widget {
    MyWidget::List(list) => f.render_widget(list, ...),
    MyWidget::Block(block) => f.render_widget(block, ...),
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey i tried your enum approach. 
```
self.terminal.draw(|f| {
    for i in 0..self.widgets.len() {
        match &self.widgets[i] {
            Widgets::Block(block) => f.render_widget(block, self.chunks[i]),
            Widgets::List(list) => f.render_widget(list, self.chunks[i]),
        }
    }
})?;
```

But I keep getting this error

```
the trait bound `&tui::widgets::Block<'_>: tui::widgets::Widget` is not satisfied
the trait `tui::widgets::Widget` is implemented for `tui::widgets::Block<'a>`
```

Comment: Read the error message properly. You are taking a reference and references don't implement Widget. Don't iterate on the length. Use self.widgets.into_iter().enumerate(). You need the actual widget and not a reference to it.